# Accessing The Callable Object a boost::thread Was Constructed With

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am using Boost 1.49 and MSVC10.

If a `boost::thread` is constructed with a callable object<sup>1</sup>, and that object has member functions or variables I want to access from *outside the context of the `thread`*, how do I get to the callabe object?

For example, I have implemmented a simple application that spawns 5 worker threads, saved to a `vector<boost::thread*>` local to `main()`.  Each of those threads is instantiated with a callable object, `Gizmo` which takes one `char` parameter in its constructor.  This `char` is saved as a `std::string` member variable in the `Gizmo` class.  Each thread will `cout` the saved `string`, then sleep for 250 ms.  It continues in this loop forever, until somehow the saves `string`'s value becomes "die".

[Short, Self Contained, (Hopefully) Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

boost::mutex cout_mtx;

class Gizmo
{
public:
    Gizmo(const string& state) : state_(state) {};
    Gizmo(Gizmo&& rhs) : state_(std::move(rhs.state_)) {};
    virtual ~Gizmo()
    {
        bool b = true;
    }
    void operator()();

    string state_;
};

void Gizmo::operator()()
{
    while( state_ != "die" )
    {
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock scoped_lock(cout_mtx);
            cout << state_ << flush;
        }
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(250));
    }
}

boost::thread* start_thread(char c)
{
    Gizmo g(string(1,c));
    return new boost::thread(g);
}

int main()
{
    vector<boost::thread*> threads;

    string d=".*x%$";
    for( string::const_iterator it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); ++it )
    {
        threads.push_back(start_thread(*it));
    }

    for( auto th = threads.begin(); th != threads.end(); ++th )
        (*th)->join();
}
```

Now I want to make a code change in `main()` which will:

1. Get the first `thread` in the `vector`
2. Get the `Gizmo` object contained within that `thread`
3. Set it's `state_` to "die"

How do I get the `Gizmo` within the thread?

```
for( auto th = threads.begin(); th != threads.end(); ++th )
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    Gizmo& that_gizmo = (*th)-> ??? ;  // WHAT DO I DO?
    that_gizmo.state_ = "die";
}
```

---

(1) A *callable object* in this context means a `class` with an `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `boost::thread` does not provide the ability to get the callable object.  `boost::thread` has a default constructor, so it does not know the callable type or function that will serve as the thread's entry point.  Also, if `boost::thread` did not perform type erasure, then it would no longer be possible to manage threads with different entry points in the same collection or thread pool.  For example, `std::vector< boost::thread< Gizmo > >` could only manage `Gizmo` threads, while `std::vector< boost::thread >` can manage `Gizmo` threads and non-`Gizmo` threads.

Instead of having to manage `Gizmo` and `boost::thread` objects in separate list, or creating a new type to pair the two together, consider associating the two via `std::pair` or `boost::tuple`.  For example:

```
std::vector< boost::tuple< boost::thread*, Gizmo > > threads;
```

Also, if the threads end up having multiple types used for the entry point, and each type requires its own form of shutdown, consider performing type erasure via `boost::function`.
For example:

```
void shutdown_gizmo( Gizmo& );

boost::function< void() > fn = boost::bind( shutdown_gizmo, boost::ref( gizmo ) );

// The tuple now contains a function object, decoupling it from Gizmo objects,
// and allowing other shutdown methods to be paired with threads.
typedef boost::tuple< boost::thread*, boost::function< void() > > tuple_t;
std::vector< tuple_t > threads;
```

With any solution, just be careful about maintaining the scope of the `Gizmo` object, as well as maintaining a handle to the correct `Gizmo` object.  It can be fairly easy to unintentionally obtain handles to copies of the actual `Gizmo` object.

Comment: This closeley resembles my final solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your start_thread() method is creating a temporary, stack object that is then being passed to the thread. Instead, you should create a vector of Gizmo objects in your main(), and then pass each member of that vector(a Gizmo) to boost's thread constructor. I don't see any reason why you should specifically obtain the thread's callable object when you can store a
reference to it in a vector in your main function.

Remember to synchronize setting of the state between the main thread and the boost thread that checks it.

Comment: +1 I see what you're getting at, similar to another suggestion here.  The reason I didn't want to maintain a list of `Gizmo`s and another list of `thread`s is because the thread already has the `Gizmo`, encapsulated within it's data members.  Maintaining two seperate lists, and keeping them synchronized, is a level of complexity that should not be necesarry.  At least, in an ideal world -- which boost, apparently, is not.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not implement a `start_thread` class, giving you access to the functor, instead of a function, and keep a vector of pointers to these? Something along the lines of (details to be ironed out, none of this is tested):

```
class start_thread {
 public:
  explicit start_thread(char c) : gizmo_(std::string(c,1)), t_(gizmo_) {}
  void join() { t_.join();}
  const Gizmo& callable() const { return gizmo_;}
  Gizmo& callable() { return gizmo_;}
 private:
  Gizmo gizmo_;
  boost::thread t_;
}
```

You need to pass the `gizmo_` to the thread constructor as a `boost::ref(gizmo_)`.

Comment: +1:  Yes, I suppose that I could.  I had hoped that I could use built-in facilities, rather than constructing some kind of encapsulating device.  By doing as you suggest, I'll also have to implement some kind of container class with a `join_all()` type function, etc.  I can do all this; I'd just rather not if I don't have to.

Comment: @JohnDibling yes, it is a pity there isn't a handle to the callable, but I guess that could complicate synchronization.